# Save user form input info for later visits with PHP cookies?

Tags: php, html, forms, cookies

Basically I want to create a cookie in PHP that remembers what a user has entered into a form (that directs to a separate page), so that anytime they come back to the page, the form is already prepopulated with whatever information they put into it the first time around.

I've looked everywhere and can't really find a good answer for how to do this. This is how my code is configured right now (which isn't working).

PHP:

```
$fname =  $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

if( ( $fname != null ) and ( $lname != null ) )
{
  setcookie( "fname", $fname, time() + 36000 );
  setcookie( "lname", $lname, time() + 36000 );
  exit();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="hidden.php">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['fname'])){echo $fname;} else {echo "";} ?>"/></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['lname'])){echo $lname;} else {echo "";} ?>"/></p>
```

Any mind telling me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how cookies work in PHP, but it looks like you set the cookie but never get the values back out of the cookie when the page loads.  Try loading the cookie values into your fname and lname variables when the page loads.

Comment: Yeah, PHP cookies and JavaScript cookies work pretty differently. In PHP, the "<?php if(isset($fname)){print stripslashes($fname);}else{print "";} ?>" that's in the form is my equivalent of the "getcookie" function. Thank you though!

Comment: I've never worked with cookies in javascript and I think you misunderstood my comment... What I mean is you have a variable called $fname which you put into a cookie using "setcookie" but nowhere in your code do you pull a value OUT of a cookie and set the value of $fname to what was in the cookie

Comment: Right, I see what you were talking about. For whatever reason, the post wasn't showing some of my code, so I just edited it to show that I define those variables from the very beginning.

Comment: see @RST's answer, you need to get the values from the COOKIE array.

Comment: I've tried that and it's still not working. I'll update the code in the post though.

Comment: okay... You need to get the values from $_POST (and set the cookie values) only if it's a POST request, and from $_COOKIE if it's a GET request.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php if(isset($fname))...
```

should be

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['fname']))
```

the same goes for the lname command

edit (not sure if this is your setup but if you put the next code in a file it should work)

```
<?php
$fname =  $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

if( ( $fname != null ) and ( $lname != null ) )
{
  setcookie( "fname", $fname, time() + 36000 );
  setcookie( "lname", $lname, time() + 36000 );
}

echo "post fname ".$_POST['fname']."<BR>";
echo "post lname ". $_POST['lname']."<BR>";
echo "cookie ". $_COOKIE['fname']."<BR>";
echo "cookie ". $_COOKIE['lname']."<BR>";
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="hidden.php">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['fname'])){echo $_COOKIE['fname'];} else {echo "";} ?>"/></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" maxlength="40" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['lname'])){echo $_COOKIE['lname'];} else {echo "";} ?>"/></p

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried that since I posted this and it still isn't working?

Comment: Is the phpcode in hidden.php the file the form submits its data to? Is there any other code in that file? Do the values get transfered properly? Did you echo $_POST variables to test this?

Comment: try setting this command {echo $fname;} to {echo $_COOKIE['fname']}

Comment: change this command if(isset($_COOKIE['fname'])){echo $fname;} else {echo "";}   to   if(isset($_COOKIE['fname'])){echo "cookie set";} else {echo "no cookie set";}

Comment: That would just echo the literal words "cookie set" or "no cookie set". I feel like I should say that I've tried messing with the "if the cookie is set then do this and if not then do this" enough to establish that it's not a problem with that line of code, it's with the configuration of the cookie itself.

Comment: Ok, for me it isn't clear whether the cookie is not created or if you are saving an empty cookie. Also be sure the setting of the cookie is the first output of the php file. There should be no whitespace at all before the php starts.

Comment: I've tried echoing random things in the else {} part of the function and that always shows up, so I'm pretty sure the cookie is not being created or saved at all. And no, there is no whitespace.

Comment: I have added some example code to my original answer. The echo commands are there for testing only, of course.